# Pass Data From AppDelegate into UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

How to pass data from AppDelegate Class into Custom ViewController?

```
import UIKit
import LocalAuthentication

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    public var config: PasscodeConfig!

    func GetAppDelegate(){
        print("\(self.config)") /// nil %(
    }

    override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.GetAppDelegate()
}
...
}
```

unfortunately the variable **config** returns - nil
AppDelegate:

```
   @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var appCoordinator: AppCoordinator!

    var code = ""
lazy var passcode: Passcode = {
    let config = PasscodeConfig(passcodeGetter: {
        return self.code
        // Return code as string
    }, passcodeSetter: { code in
        self.code = code
         // Save new code
    }, biometricsGetter: {
        return true
        // return Should use biometrics (Touch ID or Face ID) as Bool
    })

    let passcode = Passcode(window: self.window, config: config)

    return passcode
}()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        appCoordinator = AppCoordinator(window: window!)
        appCoordinator.start()

        self.passcode.authenticateWindow()

        return true
    }
...
}
```

- Passcode Class

  import UIKit
  import LocalAuthentication

  protocol PassDelegate: class {
      func jumpToHomePage()
      func jumpToOnboardingPage()
  }

  public class Passcode {

  ```
  public var config: PasscodeConfig!
  public var isPresented = false
  private var appDelegateWindow: UIWindow?

  private var authenticationViewController: PasscodeViewController?
  private lazy var passcodeWindow: UIWindow = {
      let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

      window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 0)
      window.makeKeyAndVisible()

      return window
  }()

  public init(window: UIWindow?, config: PasscodeConfig) {
      self.appDelegateWindow = window
      self.config = config

      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.willEnterForeground), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.didEnterBackground), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)

      let context = LAContext()
      var error: NSError?

      if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
          switch context.biometryType {
          case .faceID:
              self.config.biometricsString = "Face ID"
              self.config.reason = localized("biometricsReasonFaceID")
          case .touchID:
              self.config.biometricsString = "Touch ID"
              self.config.reason = localized("biometricsReasonTouchID")
          default:
              break
          }
      } else {
          self.config.biometricsString = nil
      }
  }

  @objc func willEnterForeground() {
      self.config.foreground = true
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.authenticationViewController?.biometrics()
      }
  }

  @objc func didEnterBackground() {
      self.config.foreground = false
  }

  // MARK: - Public

  public func authenticateWindow(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
      guard !isPresented, let viewController = self.load(type: .authenticate, completion: completion) else { return }

      viewController.dismissCompletion = { [weak self] in self?.dismiss() }

      passcodeWindow.windowLevel = .init(2)
      passcodeWindow.rootViewController = viewController

      self.isPresented = true
  }

  public func authenticate(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
      return self.load(type: .authenticate, completion: completion)
  }

  public func authenticate(on viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
      guard let target = self.authenticate(completion: completion) else { return }
      viewController.present(target, animated: animated)
  }

  public func askCode(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
      return self.load(type: .askCode, completion: completion)
  }

  public func askCode(on viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
      guard let target = self.askCode(completion: completion) else { return }
      viewController.present(target, animated: animated)
  }

  public func changeCode(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) -> UIViewController? {
      return self.load(type: .changeCode, completion: completion)
  }

  public func changeCode(on viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
      guard let target = self.changeCode(completion: completion) else { return }
      viewController.present(target, animated: animated) /// Отображение viewController

  }


  // MARK: - Private

  private func load(type: PasscodeType, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) -> PasscodeViewController? {
      let bundle = Bundle(for: PasscodeViewController.self)
      let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: bundle)
      guard let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PasscodeViewController") as?
          PasscodeViewController else {
          return nil
      }

      viewController.authenticatedCompletion = completion
      viewController.type = type
      viewController.config = config

      self.authenticationViewController = viewController

      return viewController
  }

  private func dismiss(animated: Bool = true) {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.isPresented = false
          self.appDelegateWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 1)
          self.appDelegateWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()

          UIView.animate(
              withDuration: 0.5,
              delay: 0,
              usingSpringWithDamping: 1,
              initialSpringVelocity: 0,
              options: [.curveEaseInOut],
              animations: { [weak self] in
                  self?.passcodeWindow.alpha = 0
              },
              completion: { [weak self] _ in
                  self?.passcodeWindow.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level(rawValue: 0)
                  self?.passcodeWindow.rootViewController = nil
                  self?.passcodeWindow.alpha = 1
              }
          )
      }
  }
  ```

  }

PasscodeConfig Class

```
public class PasscodeConfig {

    var foreground = true
    var biometricsString: String?
    public var biometrics: String? { return biometricsString }
    public var autoBiometrics = false /// Флаг Включения Аутентификации по Биометрии

    public var reason: String?

    public var colors = PasscodeColors(dark: false, mainTint: UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.48, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0), buttonTint: .black, biometrics: (.white, UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.48, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)), text: .black)

    public var passcodeGetter: (() -> String)
    public var passcodeSetter: ((String) -> Void)
    public var biometricsGetter: (() -> Bool)

    public init(passcodeGetter: @escaping (() -> String), passcodeSetter: @escaping ((String) -> Void), biometricsGetter: (() -> Bool)? = nil) {
        self.passcodeGetter = passcodeGetter
        self.passcodeSetter = passcodeSetter
        self.biometricsGetter = biometricsGetter ?? { true }
    }
}

public struct PasscodeColors {
    public var mainTint: UIColor
    public var buttonTint: UIColor
    public var biometrics: (UIColor, UIColor)
    public var text: UIColor
    public var dark: Bool

    public init(dark: Bool, mainTint: UIColor, buttonTint: UIColor? = nil, biometrics: (UIColor, UIColor)? = nil, text: UIColor) {
        self.mainTint = mainTint
        self.buttonTint = buttonTint ?? mainTint
        self.biometrics = biometrics ?? (text, mainTint)
        self.text = text
        self.dark = dark
    }

    public init() {
        self.mainTint = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.48, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0) ///
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.buttonTint = .label
            self.biometrics = (.label, mainTint)
            self.text = .label
        } else {
            self.buttonTint = .black
            self.biometrics = (.black, mainTint)
            self.text = .black
        }
        self.dark = false
    }
}
```

Moreover the variable **config** must be initialized before loading View.

What I need to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to put your setup code in an AppDelegate method, and not as a lazy var.

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`

Are you able to post what the `Passcode` and `PasscodeConfig` classes look like please?

Comment: Passcode and PasscodeConfig classes added at the bottom of question

Comment: Thank you for adding. Did you try adding the initialization code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: Added calling an authentication method only